# Remove downloads or remove from library for duplicate playlist?

Tags: iphone, music, playlist

I have a playlist that I sync between iTunes and my iPhone on iOS 10.3.1. Sometimes I see that a playlist gets duplicated with the number 1 after the name. I want to delete the duplicated playlist from my iPhone, but I get a concerning dialog, asking if I want to remove downloads ore remove the playlist from the library.

I'm not quite sure what it's asking. Can someone explain this? Any downloaded songs from iTunes I want to stay on the phone as part of the original playlist and in general, but I want that second playlist itself to disappear.

[image: remove playlist dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove Downloads** will leave the playlist in your library, but remove the music files associated with the songs in that playlist from your phone, thus freeing up storage. It's a quick method to bulk-remove songs from your phone.

**Delete from Library** will remove the playlist itself from your media library (including iCloud Music Library if you use iTunes Match or MUSIC). However whatever music files you've already downloaded will remain on your phone.

In your case, you should **Delete from Library** if you are certain the playlist is a duplicate.